# Sending MMSs with a subject line

Tags: mms-gateway

We have been recently asked to add ability to send and receive MMS to our FLEX application. Our initial plan was to use our existing functionality instead i.e. send an SMS with a subject line. When the client responses to the message with an MMS (because the SMS will become an MMS when the client attaches the required picture) the message will be routed to MMSC who has been requested to forward that message to us an email (because again our application already has ability to receive and process emails built in).

Based on my research I've found that:
1. If you add a subject line to an SMS, the SMS automatically because an MMS meaning we will need to add ability to interact with the MMS gateway. I'm fine with this.

Now my question is, if we send an MMS with a specific subject line, when that the client receives and responds to the MMS, will the subject line be automatically carried back to us like it is done on emails? The information that we will be carrying on that subject line is very important for the correct routing of that reply. Secondly, does anyone know of a website that already has MMS sending functionality. I would like to test this before going further with my design.